Altair - Display multiple names in a tooltip from overlapping points
I am working on a visualization to show when pokemon become available in Pokemon Emerald. After scraping data, I am now beating my head against the wall on how to make multiple names show up when points are overlapping. For example, Sceptile, Blaziken, and Swampert (the final evolution of the regional starting pokemon) all become available at the same level and in the same route, which means their points in the scatterplot will be overlapping. The problem is that I specify the tooltip to display 'name', but this only shows the name of the pokemon on top of the 'stack' (in the plot below, it shows 'Swampert'), instead of showing all pokemon names that are overlapping points ('Swampert','Blaziken','Sceptile'). How do I make the tooltip for all points in the stack visible?
Here is the code for my basic chart:
chart = alt.Chart(plot_emerald_pokemon).mark_point().encode(
    x = alt.X('earliest_route:N', sort='y'),
    y = alt.Y('obtain_level:Q'),
    tooltip = 'name',
    color = alt.Color('type1:N'),
).properties(
    height=400,
    width=1200
)

chart

example_plot
I have tried following various examples with no luck.
One that uses a mark_rule to filter.
One that uses transform_lookup.

I don't think there is a built-in way to do that. A workaround could be to group the data by your X and Y encoding and concatenate the name column for the groups in a new column that you display for the tooltip (either using pandas or tranforms in altair). Or you could add some jitter to the chart if you are ok with the points not being in the exact right space

Thanks for your response. I ended up going with creating a list similar to your concatenate suggestion to display them all. I do like the idea of the jitter, though, so I may try that as well and see which I like better.

UPDATE
I have figured out that if I create a list of pokemon that are in the 'stack', then just display the list of names in the tooltip. I would like to know if there was a way to do it without creating the list of names, so that I may preserve some of the other data in my dataframe.
new plot with list of names
